# Find the value of $a$ and $b$ in $ F(x) = a + b \arcsin x $

Tags: probability

Given $X$ is a continuous random variable and its probability distribution function is
$$F(x)=
\begin{cases}
0, & x < -1, \\
a+b\arcsin x, & -1 \le x < 1, \\ 
1, & x \ge 1 
\end{cases}$$

I find the value of $b$ in this way.
$$F'(x) = f(x), \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)\, dx = 1, \text{ so } b= \frac1\pi$$
How can I find the value of $a$?

Comment: Look when $x=-1$, what is the value of the function?

Comment: Just let $x=1$ or $-1$ and use the continuity. No need to integral.

Comment: @AndrewT. I've fixed the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no discrete mass at $1$. So 
$$\lim_{x\to 1^-}(a+b\arcsin x)=1.$$
There is also no discrete mass at $-1$. Use that to get another equation.

Comment: Does $x→1^−$ have a meaning of approaching 1 from the left? and $1^+$ means from the right?

Comment: Yes, your reading of the notation is the right one.